# Importing LTSpice plot data in to Excel

Tags: ltspice, analysis

Firstly, apologies as it is more of an Excel-LTSpice question than electronics.
I have a question regarding “cleaning” the data from LTSpice. I attached a small sample of data representing the gain and phase response of my system. I saved the plot as a text file and opened it with Excel.

```
Freq.   V(v)                
5.00E+05    (2.51708973529035e+001dB,8.82394560846697e+001°)
5.12E+05    (2.53707554889253e+001dB,8.82111890032527e+001°)
5.24E+05    (2.55706073625856e+001dB,8.81819749877493e+001°)
5.36E+05    (2.57704526603472e+001dB,8.81517986557393e+001°)
5.48E+05    (2.59702910547878e+001dB,8.81206441222914e+001°)
```

I would like to use gain value only and delete the phase. Sadly, it is the same cell. I am sure it is a basic excel function however not knowing what I am looking for makes it difficult. Is there any other way to import data from LTSpice?

Answer (score 1):

When importing raw text into a spreadsheet, choose comma for the delimiter then they can be classified as number , general, text or ignore and
you may also add special characters like (

To delete the suffix units use a column to truncate the imported column, such as =RIght(cell,start,LENGTH) if my memory serves me.  Then copy down.

Or you can use search and replace but it still might be text

Comment: Thank you. A bit annoying that they keep this format however there might be a good reason. Got the desired result using: 1st column =LEFT(B2,FIND("e",B2)-1) and 2nd column =RIGHT(H2,LEN(H2)-1). Now I can turn my focus on the electronics side of it!

Comment: Re: "*Is there any other way to import data from LTSpice?*" -- yes, [`ltsputil`](https://groups.io/g/LTspice/files/z_yahoo/Util/ltsputil) (registration required to avoid spammers), but this turns out to be more of an Excel/spreadsheet thing. Alternatively, you could use `.opt meascplxfmt=cartesian` and get the real/imag quantities, then use `hypot()`.